# vncserver has wrong hostname

Tags: windows-7-x64, hostname, vnc

I had to change the name of the windows 7 system.  Unaccountably, vncserver is still using the old computer name. This was RealVnc free version.  I re-installed but it is still using the old computer name.

I had a Z400 motherboard go bad and it took the disk drive.  I replaced the motherboard, $39 was cheap, and I cloned one of my other Z400 workstation C drives using Acronis.  I booted the replacement motherboard with the cloned copy, changed its name to the old defective one, and activated windows.  When It rebooted, vncserver still had the old computer name and I cannot get rid of it and it is conflicting with the vncserver on the other Z400 since they both use the same name.  There is no option in the server to use a different name that I can find anywhere.

IPs are different and all system behave fine.  I can ping and even access shares using their names.  The problem system clearly shows the correct name but, unaccountably, vncserver is using the wrong name.

This system will be upgraded to 10 in a few days, maybe the problem will go away when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!  First I had to log in and reduce the number of clients to under 5 as that was my limit.  Then I had to remove the problem system's leftover name.  This was all done at realvnc web site.  Once under 5 systems then I could add the problem one and once it connected to realvnc's cloud then it got the correct name.  This was an artifact of having more then 5 systems when I was only licensed for 5.   The "6th" one worked locally as its setup was still valid, but it was refused connection to the cloud so it never got to change its name.  It "worked" until I did a flushdns and its old setup was no longer valid.

Comment: I received a badge for most popular Queston here, yet I have 0 points and am still banned due to too many 0 questions.  Those of you that looked this up can you please upvote it.  Thanks!